# Cannot load files when paste URL manually Angular 2 routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, paste, manual

I make this routing config

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path:'/profile/:id',name:'Profile',component:ProfileComponent
  },
  // else
  {
    path: '/**',
    redirectTo: ['Home']
  }
])
```

and used this to navigate Profile with parameter {id:5}

```
<a [routerLink]="['Profile', {id:5}]" >Go </a>
```

i added to  *index.html*  head this base

```
<base href="/">
```

**It successfully navigated to**

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/1
```

**and worked fine**

but when i paste same URL manual in browser and hit enter it give me this error

[image]

Error happen because files are not loaded from root directory

```
http://localhost:3000
```

but browser trying  to load them form relative URL directory

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/1
```

**UPDATE: I am using angular 7 now, this kind of problem is fixed without need to add any thing**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved that problem by adding `#` to my routes, for example `http://localhost:3000/#/profile/1`, you can try to do the same. Someone may have better fix for this problem though. Anyway, my solution is adding `HashLocationStrategy` to `AppModule` providers:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

Of course, before that, you need to import `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

If you are using RC4 or lower, you add this to your `bootstrap` method, for example:

```
bootstrap(
AppComponent,
    [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ]);
```

Comment: where i can add this
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }

Comment: @amrabdulaziz Did my best to explain, can't do better than this.

Comment: i cannot load 
import { LocationStrategy,HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/common';

Comment: @amrabdulaziz I guess you are using very old version, try this then: `import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/platform/common';`

Comment: not worked
i am using 
"name": "angular2",
 "version": "2.0.0-beta.7",

Comment: Then this is it: `import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';`. Why are you using such an old version of Angular? It is recommended that you update to latest version ASAP.

Comment: how to update this ? 
 "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  }

Comment: A bit late in the show but facing similar issue.
For head start i am using Angular 6.
My issue is when i paste the url of my application for e.g. `http://localhost:4200/#/verified/someComponent` where `someComponent` is the path of my component defined in `route` then i am getting redirected to home page which is `http://localhost:4200/#/`. 
FYI i have first used `{usehash: true}` then`{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` but none of them is working for the first time it redirects me to homepage only then the routing works.

Answer (score 5):

Thats pretty simple.

When you refresh or manually copy paste URL in address bar, you need to have ***server side configuration (probably server side routing)*** to identify and redirect (with **PathLocationStrategy**) to destination page.

Angular routing is at client side and if you want to do the same with working condition, you need to use **HashLocationStrategy**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express Server. You can use another middleware package called express-history-api-fallback. Use the below code into your server.js

```
import fallback from 'express-history-api-fallback'
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const root = `${__dirname}/public`
app.use(express.static(root))
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root }))
```

If you are using a Webpack server. THere is an option in the webpack server configuration options "historyApiFallback". Set this value to true for your case.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/main.ts'),
    target: "web",
    output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, './comp'),
       publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
       filename: 'app.bundle.js',
       chunkFilename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
...
}
```

By using this approach you are asking the browser to store the urls(in the browser) into the cache, effectively asking the server to fallback to index.html